# Wired Earphone/Headphone Buttons to Control System Volume on Ubuntu

Tags: sound, headphones

I am trying to control the music/audio volume which is being played through earphones using the remote buttons present on my wired earphone. The buttons work with most of the Android devices but do not work with Ubuntu.

How can I get the volume control buttons on my earphones get working with my device running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? Also, if it is not possible, then why?

I would like to see if I need to change some system settings for that, or maybe need to install an app or a plugin or run a Terminal command or edit some files.

---

I tried running the the `xev` command on Terminal to check if the system is receiving any input when the keys on the earphones are pressed according to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3vjujm/how_can_i_playpause_a_song_with_the_headset/cxoz3kx/) reply to a Reddit post. And it shows no output for that.

It seems that the buttons should work according to the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-volume.html.en) which states:

> If you have external speakers, you can also change the volume using the speakers’ volume control. Some headphones have a volume control too.

My question is similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057861/headphone-volume-button-to-control-ubuntu-volume) question on Ask Ubuntu for Bluetooth Audio. But I need the solution specifically for wired headsets that work with Android.

I also came across a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965409/bose-qc20-volume-control-buttons-not-working) specific to a particular headphone on Ask Ubuntu. But I am looking for a more generalized solution for wired earphones/headphones that work with Android.

I am using [Mi Earphones (with in-built mic)](https://store.mi.com/in/item/3180400003) which has three buttons and running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS running on Dell Vostro 3558.

Comment: Are the keys recognized when you press them?  (ie. I'm suggesting you run `xev` and see if they are recognized by your system when pressed). If that's the case, I'd consider creating shortcuts that adjust volume for those keystrokes.  I've also noticed when two keyboards (with media keys) are attached, only one set may work (ie. if you have media volume keys on keyboard, secondary sets may fail) though this seems hardware specific (different on different boxes, different hardware/bios configs etc)

Comment: @guiverc , I have tried running `xev` in Terminal and then pressing the keys on the earphone. There is no additional output in the Terminal. (I have probably already mentioned that in my question as "And it shows no output for that." ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ )

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?